# Is it possible define a Java generic class with <T, Class> parameters?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I am trying to define a base class as:

```
public abstract class BaseClass <T, R> implements Interface1 <T>, Interface2 <R>{}
```

and in a subclass do

```
public abstract class SubClass1 <T, String>extends BaseClass <T, String>{}
```

Basically fix one parameter type and keep the other 1 generic for whoever extends SubClass1.
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Just declare one type parameter, not two, when declaring the subclass then. Is `public abstract class SubClass1<T> extends BaseClass <T, String>{}` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. The syntax for `SubClass1` would be:

```java
public abstract class SubClass1<T> extends BaseClass<T, String> {}
```

So not `SubClass1<T, String>`, just `SubClass1<T>`, since that is the only generic parameter for this particular class.